# Firebase: change the location of the service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to use Firebase messaging (web). Firebase by default searches for the file "firebase-messaging-sw.js" which holds the service worker.

The service worker script is expected to be on the absolute path of the application! For example : http://localhost/firebase-messaging-sw.js

How to change this default location?! Searching the official docs I found this method: `useServiceWorker` which accepts a service worker registeration, but trying to use it I get an error that the method doesn't even exist!

So, How to change the location of the service worker for firebase messaging?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As Michael has called out, the method to use is `useServiceWorker(<registration>)`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#useServiceWorker

The Messaging class is what is returned when you call`firebase.message()`.

So the sample would be:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./example/sw.js')
.then((registration) => {
  messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

  // Request permission and get token.....
});
```

I just tried this on the demo app on Github without issue: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. See @Hamid Mayeli's answer.

Comment: The sample code doesn't exist in the repo

Answer (score 22):

I know that it is an old question but as `useServiceWorker` is deprecated now, it is good to mention that you can pass the service worker directly to the `getToken`. Current [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging?authuser=0#optional-options:-serviceworkerregistration:-serviceworkerregistration;-vapidkey:-string)

```js
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

const token = await messaging.getToken({
            serviceWorkerRegistration: registration,
            vapidKey: "",
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Hamid, I followed your method to access the token but for the function `onBackgroundMessage` i'm getting this error - FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a service worker context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw).

could you please guide me on how to fix it?

Comment: you must type this script into  

`navigator.serviceWorker.register('./example/sw.js')
.then((registration) => {

const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

const token = await messaging.getToken({
            serviceWorkerRegistration: registration,
            vapidKey: "",
        });

});
`

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to do `firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration)` and pass in an existing service worker registration. Note that you should do this as early as possible, before any calls to e.g. `getToken()` or `onMessage()`.

Comment: Yes, sure. But trying this I get `method doesn't exist` !

Comment: This works for me -- are you sure that you did `firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker()` and not `firebase.messaging.useServiceWorker()`?

Comment: Also note that this API was added in version 3.5.0 of the library, so make sure you've updated to at least that version.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh, I followed your instructions like above in quickstart app, but I still get  **TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://xxxxxx.net/') with script ('https://dmsxxxx.net/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script**  error. Still firebsace looking in this https://dmsxxxx.net/firebase-messaging-sw.js location only.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is:

```js
const vapidKey = 'foo123...';
const serviceWorkerRegistration = await navigator
    .serviceWorker
    .register('/build/firebase-messaging-service-worker.js');

await getToken(messaging, {
    vapidKey,
    serviceWorkerRegistration,
})...
```

But note that if you copy this code the scope gets wrong I think (because of the path, in my example: `/build/...`).

Answer (score 0):

By using `useServiceWorker(registration)` you can use `notificationonclick` event on Firebase push messaging via exiting service worker.

`firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration)` is working and solved my problem, but keep in mind that I don't know if:

- this is a **secure way** to get payload from the server.
- this is the best way to handle push notifications.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or are you asking questions (the bullet points) yourself?

Comment: The bullet points are my queries, I dont have idea about security and performance while using Firebase Messaging with service worker. As this question is related to this topic, i am not going to create separate question.

Comment: I have edited the wording in your answer, so your bullet points are now considerations to other users (instead of questions). Your answer is a good addition to this question, thanks!