# How to to register firebase-messaging-sw and app's serviceWorker?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have 2 service worker files, one is `serviceWorker.js` which has the PWA functionality to install and cache the data. The other one is `firebase-messaging-js` for sending a notification.

How do we integrate the code and register these 2 as a whole so both the functionalities work?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66285624/385997